# Python says that there is no attribute for a class that I made

Tags: python, pygame, pong

So I was making a Pong style game in Python with Pygame and I came across something. It said that `'function' object has no attribute 'x'`. The classes that I used are here. Please help me because I have not used Python for a long time and I do not know what this error means.

```
from math import pi, sin, cos

class Vector:

    def __init__ (self, x = 0, y = 0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @classmethod
    def random ():
        angle = random(0, 2 * pi)
        x = cos(angle)
        y = sin(angle)
        return Vector(x, y)
```

```
from Vector import Vector

class Ball:

    def __init__ (self, size):
        self.position = Vector(size[0] / 2, size[1] / 2)
        self.velocity = Vector.random
        self.scale = Vector(100, 100)
```

```
import pygame

from Ball import Ball

def main ():
    pygame.init()

    size = (1600, 900)

    window = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Pong")

    ball = Ball(size)

    frameRate = 60

    run = True

    while run:
        pygame.time.delay(int(frameRate / 1000))

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        window.fill((0, 0, 0))
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 255, 255), (ball.position.x, ball.position.y, ball.scale.x, ball.scale.y))
        pygame.display.update()

        # This is where the error happened.

        ball.position.x += ball.velocity.x
        ball.position.y += ball.velocity.y

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `self.velocity = Vector.random` is assigning the *function* `Vector.random` to `self.velocity`. Note, your `@classmethod` signature is also incorrect. Please do not spam your own question with this sort of this: "StackOverflow wants me to use more words"

Comment: Why did you use `Vector` and not PyGame's `Vector2` - https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2 ?

Answer (score 2):

Your `Vector` class has a few errors, and as @juanpa.arrivillaga says, you're returning the function reference rather than an object by assigning `... = Vector.random` as opposed to `... = Vector.random()`

Your code would probably be better if it used the built-in PyGame Vector object:

```
import pygame
import random
import math

class MyVector( pygame.math.Vector2 ):
    def __init__( self, x, y ):
        super().__init__( x, y )

    @staticmethod
    def getRandomVector():
        angle = random.random() * math.pi
        x = math.cos( angle )
        y = math.sin( angle )
        return MyVector( x, y )


v1 = MyVector( 3, 2 )
v2 = MyVector.getRandomVector()

print( "v1: "+str( v1 ) )
print( "v2: "+str( v2 ) )
```

Sub-classing it to add your `random()` function.  Note the use of `@staticmethod` rather than `@classmethod`.  But using inheritance to simply create only this function seems to add a bit of unnecessary complexity.  I guess if you're planning to extend the `vector` more, then sure (the base vector object already has a lot of useful functions).

Also the `math` library has no `random()` member function.  But using the `random.random()` function, which returns a number between `0.0` and `1.0`, it's easy to fix the code.